# Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?

Tags: discussion

For example, I have this neatly formatted question on another website:

- http://answers.opencv.org/question/37527/detecting-palm-lines/

What are the rules and regulations or general netiquette constraints against posting it on, say, Stack Overflow at the same time? If any?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? They are different websites on different networks? There are no duplicate checks across different sites within the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: It may be a personal issue, but I *hate* cross-posters. I visit about half a dozen forums on a regular basis, and indeed sometimes spot questions blandly copied-and-pasted from one forum to another. It leads to fragmentary solutions and double work for *everyone*. (It's also a guide of how the poster may think of a forum -- "I can post only here but I'm sure no-one knows. Better find another.")

Comment: See also: [Is it wrong to ask the same question elsewhere?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere)

Comment: I see it quite frequently, and like @Jongware, I don't like it much at all. Particularly if they don't update on other sites once they get the solution on one site, which is almost always the case. IMHO, it doesn't show a lot of respect for the people who are spending their time to try and help them. I think it's totally fine to post on one site, and then on another a couple of days later if you don't get a satisfactory answer on the first site. But I don't consider posting (often trivial) questions all over the internet at the same time good style.

Comment: Ironically, meant to ask this on stackexchange.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes, it's a personal issue. A personal opinion. If a question had no answers, or very few, and the topics was abandoned before being really exploited, it's natural and logical to try to get help elsewhere.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Standard netiquette from the last thirty or so years suggests that cross-posting is discouraged (and thus on Stack Overflow, claiming not to know this does not usually save a question from downvotes). Cross-posting has the potential to waste people's time both in reading and in responding.

However, my view is that if you have not succeeded in getting an answer in one place, it is fine to cross post **and declare that you have done so prominently** in the new post, using a hyperlink. That way, people who know the answer can check to see whether they would be duplicating an answer elsewhere before expending effort upon it.

A commenter under your question here suggests waiting a couple of days before considering a community unable to answer your question - I think this is about right. Some sites will allow you to "bump" the question by adding a dummy reply to it, but others dislike this behaviour, so try to find that out before doing so. Here on Stack Overflow, well-written questions get bumped by upvotes or by bounties.

> What are the general netiquette constraints against posting it on, say, Stack Overflow at the same time?

Don't post it at the same time (regardless of whether you acknowledge the cross-posting). I'd say that goes against the spirit of the guidelines, and it suggests to all the groups in which you are posting that you are just in a rush for an answer, and are not interested in being a member of the community.

Comment: Bumped by upvotes?

Comment: @Final, I believe that an upvoted question is more likely to be seen - either on the home page or in 'Hot' tabs. I'm not entirely sure of the algorithm, I expect it'd be noted in Meta somewhere.

Comment: My experience shows that it does not help with old questions that got no proper answers.

Comment: @FinalContest I regularly click the "unanswered" tab when browsing question tags and there an upvoted question will be placed higher in the list. I guess "bumped" isn't really the right terminology though.

Comment: **`forty or so years`???**

Comment: @charlietfl: triple question marks and emboldening should usually be accompanied by all-caps, for extra irony points `;-)`. Netiquette arguably stems from Usenet, which Wikipedia tells me started in 1980. Thus, 34 years is a bit more accurate - but that the social norms are "several decades old" is still true.

Comment: SE's algorithm for questions is different on SO and is always getting changed...

Comment: @Annonomus - the above is my view of what it should be, and (IMO) what it always has been. In what way do view it has changed, specifically?

Comment: @halfer they talk about it in the latest [SE podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/podcast-60-are-we-that-predictable/). If you don't want to listen to that: 1.) I wasn't clear in my last comment; they're always changing the SO algorythm, the rest of SE is staying the same. 2.) they have it where unanswered questions get more time on the homepage, but they're chaining it to [if I remember right] upvotes gets you time on the homepage.

Comment: @Annonomus, ah, that sounds like a good change. Thanks for the info!