# Cross-posting by user and removed question by moderator on SO in Russian. Does our SO has same rules?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, rules, cross-posting

Recently I found [this question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85) on *Meta ruSO*. I've seen some posts on *Meta SO* and on *Meta StackExchange*, BUT that question was removed by moderator with the reason (translation):

> If you will still post the same question on many web-sites, as minimum on *ruSO* everything will be removed. We want to achieve the idea of single source of knowledge.

The user posted the same question on *ruSO* and [Toster.ru](https://toster.ru/), not relatedto *StackExchange* web-site.
Question was removed by moderator [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky). Honestly, when I saw that I didn't believe, because I've never seen or heard about similar on *Big StackOverflow*, especially about "***single source of knowledge***". I found related links on *Meta SO* and on *Meta StackExchange*, but they describe mostly why it is bad for user, but I haven't met even a word about removing questions.

The most appreciated will be the answer from any of Moderators to hear official position about this on *StackOverflow* in English.

*EDIT*

Following my understanding and questions, provided by @Kendra :

1. [Is it ok to ask a question on SO and then post it on a different site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271079/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-on-so-and-then-post-it-on-a-different-site)
2. [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites)

Those answers showed (to me at least) this is not polite towards people who answer first of all. But not about restriction and that your question will be removed. 
Also I remember (unfortunately, cannot find the link right now) the answer of [Mr. Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), where he said ***"...StackOverflow oriented not on the user, but on the content..."***. So, in my understanding, the question will be answered and the question will have the variety of answers anyways. If user find the solution on another web-site he might answers his question anyways in case to close the question and share the solution (*might*). So *StackOverflow* will not loose the content from this.

Comment: Where all else was it posted. and in what language? Anyway, we frown on cross-posting: Decide on the proper SE site, give it time, and if it really does not help you might try again on another SE site, cross-linking the questions to avoid wasted effort and applying all you learned as well as properly tailoring it for the new community.

Comment: I guess the question here is: does posting the same question in two different languages make those questions "materially different", as suggested by Jeff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment181805_75012 ?

Comment: @Deduplicator, it was all in Russian. Another web-site is [Toster.ru](https://toster.ru/). In the question was meant *non-SE* web-sites.

Comment: @BradLarson, no, no, it is not about the language, but about *non-SE* web-sites. Also about the aim of Mr. Nicolas Chabanovsky about *"single source of knowledge"*.

Comment: @Yurets - OK, I guess I'm confused as to what you're asking. I thought you were saying something was cross-posted between Stack Overflow and ru.stackoverflow.com. Are you saying that something was cross-posted from another site and ru.SO? The procedures are different if we're talking about something cross-posted within the Stack Exchange network and cross-posted from sites outside of SE.

Comment: @BradLarson, so sorry for confusion. Yes, it is about ruSO and different from SE web-sites.

Comment: I knew I had seen this somewhere before: There is [Is it ok to ask a question on SO and then post it on a different site?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271079/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-on-so-and-then-post-it-on-a-different-site) which is marked as a duplicate of [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites). Both seem to say that it's fine to cross-post between _non_ network sites. It is, of course, frowned upon to cross-post between SE sites.

Comment: @Kendra With the caveat that you should follow good cross-posting etiquette: explicitly mention that you've cross-posted at someothersite.com and write an answer to the other post when one is answered. Related posts (entertainingly, they give somewhat conflicting advice): [Why is cross-posting wrong (on an external site)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141823/234299), [Does a “dupe” on another (non-SE/SO) site warrant a vote to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126920/234299), [Is it wrong to ask the same question elsewhere?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22657/234299)

Comment: As for the "single source of knowledge" part, Stack Overflow's goal is to be a high-quality knowledge repository of programming questions. Each SE site has a similar goal, only pointed to it's own specific topic. This is likely what the "single source of knowledge" was referring to. I'm afraid I don't quite understand why the mod you mention would delete a question for being cross-posted from a non-network site, especially with him adding that, but that would be for him to explain more thoroughly. Perhaps there was something more we do not know.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Of course. At the same time, that's not something we can actually 100% enforce 100% of the time. We'd have to be able to know that it actually is a cross-post by the same user and not just someone else stealing the question on the third party site, for example. In the case presented, I would assume there's something we don't know. Perhaps that's what made the mod delete the question- The user did not use good etiquette. Without more details, or input from the mentioned mod, it's really hard to say.

Comment: @Kendra, the reason of removing was translated literally. This is brief translation/explanation of what user asked. The answer of moderator aimed to show how is hard for future people who wishes to find the answer to get through different web-sites with same question. Unfortunately, I'm not able to translate whole answer, but I don't much reason. Because the aim I mentioned becomes broad and with kind of proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL, DR:

In short, there is **no formal or informal** rule that prohibits posting on other sites, so removal of that question wasn't in accordance with any [SO]'s formal or informal guidelines.

### Formal reasoning

Let us ask ourselves two things: ***Why can some questions be deleted? And do such rules apply to the question we consider?***

But hasn't the first question been already answered, has it? Yes, there is already an answer in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be
>   removed at the discretion of the community and moderators

It means that a question can be removed only in two cases:

1. When it is extremely off-topic.
2. Or when it is of very low-quality.

Does the removed post qualify under any of these? **Probably not**. If it is of sufficient quality and is on-topic, there is no formal reason to delete it.

### Informal reasoning(unspoken rules)

While there is no formal rule that can encourage us to delete such posts, aren't there also any informal rules regarding this matter? Perhaps some condensed opinion here on meta?

Yes, there are some discussions regarding out-of-site-crossposting, as it has been already mentioned by @Kendra:

1. [Is it OK to cross-post a question between non-Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266053/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-a-question-between-non-stack-exchange-and-stack-exchange)
2. [Is it ok to ask a question on SO and then post it on a different site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271079/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-on-so-and-then-post-it-on-a-different-site)
3. [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251469/should-i-ask-questions-that-have-been-answered-on-other-qa-sites)

Still, they do not boil to "cut those questions down". The consensus, rather, is:

1. To respect those who are answering the question by mentioning the cross-posting explicitly.
2. And to self-answer the question if you get the solution somewhere else.

---

### P.S.: Regarding moderator's reasoning

I can see one problem with [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky)'s [opinion regarding out-of-SO duplication](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365):

He basically says two things:

1. It is difficult to sieve through multiple sites with multiple barely discernible or even absent answers to get to the solution.
2. And that ru.SO shall become a definite reliable source of programming related Q-A format information in the [runet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runet_(terminology)).

Both these things are quite noble intentions and are in line with overall SO's paradigm.

But removing viable on-topic content from SO directly **contradicts and works against** both of his intentions:

1. User will still post his question on all those other sites. And someone will still have to search them later. But it is doubtful that many of such resources will contain the information in easily accessible question-answer format or contain it at all. And even if they will, such information **will be not on ru.SO**.
2. And such action will:

   1. Remove this information from ru.SO, thus making it lesser in scope, thus reducing its visibility and usefulness.
   2. Potentially drive the user off the site, thus loosing potential questions, answers and views he can add, thus making ru.SO less likely to be the first in search engine results.

Basically, it seems for me that he is throwing baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: Very good answer! agree with that 100%.